# Data Communication between two raspberry pi's via GPIO

Tags: i2c, spi, uart, computer-vision

Good day

I am currently implementing an autonomous quadcopter with stereo vision using raspberry Pi. One (Let's call this Pi_1) is responsible for stereo vision the other is responsible for motor control and trajectory planning (Pi_2). I was looking for a way to transfer a 480 element float vector via GPIO from Pi_1 to Pi_2. Pi_1 stereovision program runs at 2Hz while Pi_2 motor control runs at 210Hz.

> Is there any protocol fast enough to deliver this amount of information to the second raspberry pi via GPIO?

I am currently looking at SPI but I saw that the Raspberry Pi cannot be turned to a Slave making it not an option. I also looked at UART however it is too slow for my needs. All the I2c ports on the Pi are currently being used by the stereo vision cameras and the IMU's. If the gpio option is not feasible, I am also open for other suggestions such as using other hardware (middle man) or wireless options.

Comment: I don't understand why you discount the UART but consider I2C.  The UART can be driven faster than I2C.

Comment: @joan isn't uart on the raspberry pi only limited to 100kbps while i2c can be used up to 400kbps

Comment: No.  I think the maximum is 4 Mbps for the UART.

Comment: oh thanks :) do you know good resources for studying uart on the raspberry pi?

Comment: Google raspberry pi max uart speed

Comment: What's wrong with connecting the two ethernet ports together?  You should be able to get *at least* 40 Mbps that way.

Comment: @goldilocks, one of the raspi boards I am using is the raspberry pi compute module io board. :) Unfortunately it does not have an ethernet socket. :(

Comment: Same question posted on [robotics SE](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/8951/establishing-data-transfer-between-two-raspberry-pis-using-gpio).